# Dots in ENV variable in dockerfile doesn't work

Tags: docker

When I declare ENV variable with dots in name, they does not set properly. To framework that I am dockerizing requires this variable to be set:

```
  framework.config.location
```

Dockerfile

```
ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jre1.8 \
framework.config.location=$HOME/framework/config 

RUN echo $framework.config.location && \
    cd $framework.config.location
```

> .config.location
>
> /bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to .config.location

Comment: Env file works in a running container. Not when building an image. You should be using build vars instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think `framework.config.location` (and in general a string containing dots) is not a valid identifier from the perspective of Unix shells like bash.

You can however use it in ENV section of you Dockerfile: the result is something like

```
env framework.config.location=$HOME/framework/config TheCommand
```

but you can't access the variable's value through `$framework.config.location` orf `{$framework.config.location}`.
you can read it using `value=$(env | grep 'framework.config.location' |  cut -f 2 -d '=')` and then use as `$value`...

Comment: Regarding the last part of your answer, it would be nice to clarify that you cannot store that value anywhere in the Dockerfile, so it's useless if you need to use it anywhere outside that RUN command, i.e. `RUN value=$(env | grep 'framework.config.location' |  cut -f 2 -d '=') && echo $value`